# Return value from AJAX onreadystatechange Event

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have some problems with returning a value from a function into a variable. It is apparently "undefined". This apparently happens due to the asynchronity of JavaScript. But in my case I don't know how to circumvent it with "callbacks" or "promises". Please see code below. I would like to return the exchange rate saved in "value" back to "rate" and use it further in my code. Any ideas?

```js
var rate = rateCalc();
var currency = "EUR";
 
function rateCalc(){
 var value;
 if (currency != "EUR") {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var rateURL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3D"+"EUR"+"HKD"+"%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json";
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    value = json.query.results.row.rate;
    alert("At this position the value is defined: "+ value);
    return value;
   }
  }
 xmlhttp.open("GET", rateURL, true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 
 else {
  value = 1;
  return value;
 }
}
alert("The return statement somehow didn't work: "+ rate);
```

I'm a newbie, by the way. So sorry, if this question has already been asked like a million times before.

Thanks
René

Comment: You can't do that.  http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return anything from a async function in JS. So create a new function and use it as a callback function. See the below example.

```
    var rate = rateCalc();
    var currency = "EUR";

    function rateCalc(){
        var value;
        if (currency != "EUR")  {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var rateURL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3D"+"EUR"+"HKD"+"%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json";
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    value = json.query.results.row.rate;
                    alert("At this position the value is defined: "+ value);
                    valueCallBack(value); //Callback function

                }
            }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", rateURL, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }

        else {
            value = 1;
            return value;
        }
    }

   function valueCallBack(value){

     console.log("value is " + value);      
   }
```

Update : You can use the Promise API introduced in the ES6 or use JQUERY deferred objects.

Comment: Hello Jijo John and @nx0side, thanks for your replies. I guess you mean the same thing. That means all further calculations have to be done within the callback function, right? Because outside of it the variable is not recognized again.

Answer (score 0):

xmlhttp.send() shouldn't be empty. Try this. I hope it will do the job!

```
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the response value to another function so when you have a value it will be displayed without it being undefined.

Try this:

```
rateCalc();
var currency = "EUR";

function rateCalc() {
    var value;

    if (currency != "EUR")  {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var rateURL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3D"+"EUR"+"HKD"+"%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                value = json.query.results.row.rate;
                show(value);
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", rateURL, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    } else {
        value = 1;
        show(value);
    }
}

function show(rate) {
    alert("Value: "+ rate);
}
```

Comment: @René: To the comment in Jijo post: Yes, you need to operate inside of the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I changed the code now. The call back function is used for all further calculations with the called back value. Thanks again to @Jijo John and @nx0side.

```js
var currency = "HKD";
var value;
  
if (currency != "EUR")
 {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var rateURL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3D"+"EUR"+"HKD"+"%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json";
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
   {
    var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    value = json.query.results.row.rate;
    valueCallBack(value); //Callback function
   }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", rateURL, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
 }
  
else
 {
  valueCallBack(1);
 }

//in this function all further calculations with "value" need to take place.
function valueCallBack(value)
{
 //example
 var result = 70000/value;
 console.log("Result is " + result);
}
```