# give another function a boolean value depending on the xml http request status

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, callback, xmlhttprequest

### Similar Questions

Similar questions that I have already tried to apply to my case, but didn't lead to the conclusion of this problem.
If you have a similar problem however, these might be worth looking into:

- [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
- [Return value from AJAX onreadystatechange Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206435/return-value-from-ajax-onreadystatechange-event)
- [return value from onreadystatechange with callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217658/return-value-from-onreadystatechange-with-callback)

### Context

I have a form with three inputs (name, password, confirm password), that I want to validate with Javascript for certain criterias (e. g. minimum length of password, etc.). So I created the function validateForm() that does that.

One criteria is that the username shouldn't exist already. So I created the function userExists() (see below), that is called by validateForm(). userExists() works fine on its own, because it logs "Exists" or "Does not exist" correctly in the console.

### The Problem

However, I struggle hard to get a boolean (true/false) with the function *userExists()* in the function *validateForm()*.

I identified two issues that make this difficult:

1. Getting the value out of the onreadystatechange property
2. asynchronous functions: Making *validateForm()* wait for *userExists()* to finish before continuing (which I tried to solve via callback)

### The Question

How do I get the info, if the User already exists from *userExists()* to *validateForm()*?

I am new to (and a little overwhelmed by) Javascript and have been sitting on this issue for literrally two days now. I am not sure if there is a structural problem or if it is just a little syntax error. I don't know how to solve this and would be really very grateful for some help.

### Code

```js
var val;
var exists;
var performSomeAction = function (exists) {
    val = exists;
}

function validateForm() {
    const name = document.getElementById("username").value;
    //checking some inputs

    //check if the username is already in use
    console.log(nameExists);
    else if (nameExists) {
        alert("The name is already in use");
        name = "";
        return false;
    }

    //validating more inputs
}

function userExists(callback) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 204) {
            console.log("Exists");
            callback(true);
        } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 404) {
            console.log("Does not exist");
            callback(false);
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "#aLinkThatIsNotTheIssue", true);
    xmlhttp.send("");
}
```

### Result

The current output in the console is:

```
undefined
Exists
```

Comment: You have to help us out a little here. You've clearly done. your research - thanks for that. But, you provide a result that includes `returned_data` that isn't in the code you provided. Neither is the call to UserExists. You are correct in that this is an async problem that looks like you are using the `exists` or `val` or both outside of the callback function (in other words, before the callback has a chance to execute and complete). But it would be nice to see the code associated with where `returned_data` is `console.log()`'d.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I tried around a lot, that is why I messed up the explanation in relation to the code a bit. I updated my question and fortunately was able to find a solution in the meantime, which i will post here in no time in case someone has the same problem as me in the future. 
Thank you very much for your attempts in helping me with this issue, @RandyCasburn, I really appreciate it!